# Unix Date Formatting while concatenating the file name (Unix Shell Scripting)

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Required Format:

```
START_STOP_AA_07062013.txt
```

Created by me:

```
START_STOP_AA_07July13.txt
```

Script:

```
@Script Level :  

$A.Process[0].DateRange.RunDate = [String]::Format("{0:MMddyyyy}", DateTime]::Parse("${RunDate}"));
$A.Process[0].Local.FileName = "START_STOP_AA_${RunDate}.txt"

@Varible Level blank
```

Please help.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: unix language shell scripting

Comment: maybe that's what you're asking for, but that code is definitely not shell code.

Comment: @glennjackman and .. neither java nor javascript..

Comment: Looks vaguely `perl`-ish, but I'm not 100% sure on that, as I tend to avoid `perl` whe(re|n)ever possible..

Comment: It's not Perl (`.` does string concatenation, not what appears to be attribute lookup).

Answer (score 1):

You need the `date` command:

```
rundate=$(date "+%m%d%Y")
filename="START_STOP_AA_${rundate}.txt"
```

The GNU date manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation

---

Let me put on my ESP hat and <strike>guess</strike> try again:
You are given `START_STOP_AA_07062013.txt` and you want to "convert" that to `START_STOP_AA_06July2013.txt`

```
given=START_STOP_AA_07062013.txt
if [[ $given =~ (.*_)([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])(.*) ]]; then
    mon=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    year=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
    date=$( date -d "$mon/$day/$year" "+%d%B%Y" )
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${date}${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
fi
```

I would strongly recommend using the date format `YYYY-MM-DD` -- that's the only one that sorts sensibly and is unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the reply 


Rundate Variable formate reamin same as 04042014
but 
While i am concatinating its change the formate to 04April2014

Comment: See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-conversion-specifiers.html#Date-conversion-specifiers) and change `%m%d%Y` to ... something else

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow but this is a very poor quality question. Your requirements are entirely unclear (especially using the word "required" for something that you *don't* want is ... bad). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking